# Cannot find sbt in Android Studio plug-in list

Tags: android, scala, android-studio, plugins, sbt

In [this](http://scala-on-android.taig.io/editor/android-studio/) website it is explained how to enable Scala in Android studio. My problem is that "sbt" (Build Tool) is absent in my plug-in list as is shown in the guide. Though "Scala" was there and I installed it.

I though I may have to add another plug-in repo but didn't find any.

Comment: You don't need sbt plugin. Scala plugin already supports sbt. It might be an old tutorial.

Comment: No, the sbt plugin is necessary to enable better ide integration. Without it, every sbt build invoked by the ide will be slow. The plain scala plugin is sufficient for getting the project imported, but for building and running, it is best to have the additional plugin if possible

Answer (score 2):

The reason sbt is not shown is that its last version (1.8.0) is not compatible with my Android Studio (v1.5.1).